# Audit.Net Entity Framework - Independant Associations [Tables Many-To-Many]

Tags: audit.net

Hi i write because i have configured the Audit for one single table for all my entities and its working fine for the general tables in my model, but with the Many-To-Many tables i don't know how can i do for setup the "AssociationEntryRecord"? the event is fired by EF when i do one change in this tables but i don't know how saved!

Could you please help me with this questions, thanks in advance for your help & the library...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For configuring the Entity Framework event provider use the fluent API provided by `Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()`

You can include the associations as follows:

```
Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
    .ForAnyContext(config => config
        .IncludeIndependantAssociations());
```

And about your sample code (what you should have included as textual `code` and not as an image):

- The first line is not needed, since the `UseEntityFramework()` will
  override the DataProvider
- The primary key value can be calculated as: `entity.TablePk = entry.PrimaryKey.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();`